# Cluster points in regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I am trying to cluster data for a regression problem and wonder if I am way off in my approach or if there is something in it.

Problem: make a model of impact of variable L1 and L2 in Output. Output is a count variable so I use a Poisson regression.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as smf
x0 = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ffyring/draws/master/machinedata.csv',index_col=0)
model0 = smf.GLM.from_formula(formula='(Output ~ L1 + L2)',data = x0,family=smf.families.Poisson())
result0 = model0.fit()
result0.summary()
```

The output is a nice table where I can see statistics for all the regression. I have a little bit hard to interpret goodness-of-fit, but that is not my question here.

Now to my problem: I want to see if I can make better prediction of Output if I use information from partsID. My vague idea is to cluster on partsID and then use some distance-metric together with p-value or something to see if the clustering makes sense. Here is my approach this far:

```
# Now I want to see if I can do better by clustering the data by partsID. Some have lots of data, some other
# only a few. I group together the ones with not so much data

MIN_ENTRIES = 100
different_parts = x0['partsID'].value_counts()
too_few = different_parts[different_parts < MIN_ENTRIES]
x1 = x0.copy()
x1[x1['partsID'].isin(too_few.index)] = 999999
different_parts = x1['partsID'].value_counts()

# Loop over the partsID
stats = pd.DataFrame(index = different_parts.index, 
                 columns = {'noOfParts':np.int32, 'L1':np.float,'L1p':np.float,
                            'L2':np.float,'L2p':np.float})
for part in different_parts.index:
   data = x1[x1['partsID'] == part]
   model0 = smf.GLM.from_formula(formula='Output ~ L1 + L2',data = data, family=smf.families.Poisson())
   result0 = model0.fit()
   coeffs = result0.params
   pvals = result0.pvalues
   stats.at[part] = {'noOfParts' : different_parts[part],'L1' : coeffs.L1, 'L2' : coeffs.L2,'L1p' : pvals.L1, 'L2p' : pvals.L1}

#stats contains some statistics for each partID
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x=stats.L1,y=stats.L2)
```

[image]

And now I am a bit lost how I should continue. My idea was to look at the standard deviation of the coefficients in each regression and cluster points that where close together, but since I do the regression on lots of smaller datasets instead of the entire dataset, of course each smaller set fits the data better.

L1 and L2 also have a linear relationship of how large the coefficients are in the different datasets, implying a relationship between them which I have hard to say how it affects the regression.

Any ideas which approach I should use to see if I can cluster my data into subsets and take size of clusters into account to find out statistics for my coefficients in the regression?